# UIPopover Look: Ugly rounded corner edges

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopover

I put a UITableView in a UIPopover, and got these white edges instead of real rounded corners when the table view's scrollbar is visible (and, after some time, even without the scrollbar):

[image]

Is this expected behaviour? I know that UIPopover is supposed to add a clipping mask with rounded corners to child views, but I can't imagine that this should happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**EDIT** I assume u have tableView

```
[yourTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

---

```
[yourPopover.contentViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: no, does not do the trick. as i mentioned, the problem is not always visible, but only when scrolling, and after some time the problem persists even after stopping scrolling.